# Bitcoin walet not updated

Tags: bitcoin-core, balance

I have setup'd bitcoin core(Version 22.0) on my centos server with pruning set to 3GB.
Now, My friend sent me some bitcoins but my wallet still show me 0. The transactions has 41 confirmations. Please help.

Comment: is it because of bitcoin syncing is still in progress ? just a guess

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin core tells in the display whether the wallet is synchronised yet. If it isn't yet fully synchronised, it yet can't show the results of recent transactions.

Pruning affects the amount of data retained on disk. It does not reduce the amount of data that has to be obtained over the network for synchronisation.

[image: Bitcoin core, status line]